# annotation in spring boot @autowired

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

I have been coding basic java for a while and now experiencing to spring boot.

It is very often to see annotation in spring boot.

To me, annotation is to save time for developer to implement less code, by definition online. But this doesn't satisfy my question below

So far, I am experiencing @autowired. What confused me is that @autowired enable dependency injection and tell bean to configure xml (which i dont understand how useful it is yet)

For example,

```
class A {

    private int id;

    // With setter and getter method
}

class B {

    private String name;

    @Autowired 
    A a;
    
B(A a){this.a = a} ;
    
    }
}
```

However, isnt it that, in basic java, it has been allowing to pass instance as argument without @autowired? Why does this suddenly become a benefit? or what am I missing?

```
class A {

    private int id;

    // With setter and getter method
}

class B {

    private String name;

    A a;
B(A a){this.a = a} ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a benefit when you do this (although it is not recommended)

```
@Component
class A {

    private int id;

    // With setter and getter method
}

@Component
class B {

    private String name;

    @Autowired 
    A a;
    
    B() {
    
    }
       
}
```

now, assuming these classes live in the same or a sub-package of the @SpringBootApplication annotated class, will be auto-configured for you, and A will be injected into B using reflection by the Spring framework.

However, as I mentioned this is not recommended and you probably want to inject it through the constructor, since that makes your component easier to test (you can easily inject a mock in stead). Note that when you have a component/bean with a constructor that takes arguments @Autowired is inferred and spring will try to find the beans to inject into it for you.

```
@Component
class A {

    private int id;

    // With setter and getter method
}

@Component
class B {

    private String name;

    final A a;

    B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @p.streef 
When we injecting a instance into constructor, like the way I do in traditional way, we are passing a instance we created. There could be many same type of instances of A we created. How spring boot know which instances of A we created to pass into B (autowird) ? , or  it simply just create a instance of A and assign the variable in B with A type?

Comment: spring does not autowire anything you create yourself unless you actually add it to the context during startup (before autowiring happens).

Comment: when we say, with autowired, A will be injected into B , does it mean a instance of A will be created when instance B is created?  If that's the case, actually what is the difference from that assigning member A which is inside B through the constructor? I just wonder why annotation like autowired seems over applaud as I heard.

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that. First spring created a graph of dependent components and decides which to create first so it can be injected in components that depend on it.
So the idea is that you only configure/annotate classes and that spring does the actual creation, you don't actually create these components manually